# Using @ConfigurationProperties in Spring Boot Application doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, properties, configuration

I am using Spring Boot V 1.4.1 for a new application. 
My app requires two JDBC data sources and I was following the example at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources how to set it up. 
My Spring beans configuration class is annotated with `@EnableConfigurationProperties` and my first bean is defined as

```
@Primary
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "first.database")
DataSource qivsDB() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

, the second one accordingly. My `application.properties` file has properties defined like

```
first.database.url=jdbc:[redacted]
first.database.username=[redacted]
first.database.password=[redacted]
```

For reasons I not transparent to me during debugging this is failing to initialize: `Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE` - debug showed me that the builder does not have any properties set when calling `build()`.

What did I miss here?

Comment: Maybe it's about *public* modifier missing before your givsDB bean declaration

Comment: ever found a solution? I got the same exact issue

Answer (score 0):

Before you do all the debugging part, you should have a look to the auto-configuration report. If you define your own `DataSource` there's no reason for Spring Boot to start looking at what it can do for your app. So, for some reasons, that definition of yours is not applied in your app and the default in Spring Boot still applies, doesn't find any JDBC url in the default namespace and attempt to start an embedded database. You should see in the auto-config report that the `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` still matches.

I am not sure the `public` keyword has anything to do with it, though you won't get custom meta-data for that key since we only scan for public methods.